# PHP Text In Div class not show Whitespace in Text

Tags: php, whitespace

How can I show a white space between these two words [login] and [register]?

If the php code is not inside the Div class white spaces are shown but not in div class.

String for Lang:

> Bitte [LOGIN] , um Dein Abo zu buchen. Falls noch nicht geschehen, klicke hier um Dich zu [REGISTER]

what I mean:

[image]

```
<div class="icon message">
    <i class="icon secondary info sign"></i>
    <?php echo str_replace(array("[LOGIN]", "[REGISTER]"), array(' <a href="' . Url::url('/login') . '" class="bold text">' . strtolower(Lang::$word->LOGIN) . '</a>', '<a href="' . Url::url('/register') . '" class="bold text">' . strtolower(Lang::$word->REGISTER) . '</a>'), Lang::$word->FRONT_VIP_ERROR); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. For one, though, your second link (for registering) doesn't even have a leading space. Also, what does the original string look like?

Comment: Hi,
this is the original string ...

`<i class="icon secondary info sign"></i>  
    <?php echo str_replace(array("[LOGIN]", "[REGISTER]"), array(' <a href="' . Url::url('/login') . '" class="bold text">' . strtolower(Lang::$word->LOGIN) . '</a>', '<a href="' . Url::url('/register') . '" class="bold text">' . strtolower(Lang::$word->REGISTER) . '</a>'), Lang::$word->FRONT_VIP_ERROR);?></p>`

Comment: By original string I meant the one you're doing the replacement on, the `Lang::$word->FRONT_VIP_ERROR`.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but the text that is added is this:
Bitte [LOGIN] , um Dein Abo zu buchen. Falls noch nicht geschehen, klicke hier um Dich zu [REGISTER]

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I've tested with it again and I still can't reproduce. Have a look at the source of the page and share the generated HTML (edit the question, don't add new code in the comments).

Comment: Also note that the word "Logge Dich ein" is written in uppercase but as well as without whitespace it is reported in lowercase

Comment: Well, you're telling it to - `strtolower(Lang::$word->LOGIN)`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the time you are investing, I will add details to the question.